# Ansible known_hosts module ssh key propagation question

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ansible

I'm trying to craft a playbook that will update the known_hosts for a machine / user however I'm getting an error I can't make sense of.

```
---
- name: Keys
  hosts: adminslaves
  gather_facts: false
  no_log: false
  remote_user: test
  #pre_tasks:
  #  - setup:
  #     gather_subset:
  #      - '!all'
  tasks:
    - name: Scan for SSH host keys.
      shell: ssh-keyscan myhost.mydomain.com 2>/dev/null
      changed_when: False
      register: ssh_scan

      #    - name: show vars
      #      debug:
      #        msg: "{{ ssh_scan.stdout_lines }}"
      #

    - name: Update known_hosts.
      known_hosts:
        key: "{{ item }}"
        name: "{{ ansible_host }}"
        state: present
      with_items: "{{ ssh_scan.stdout_lines }}"
```

My error is   `"msg": "Host parameter does not match hashed host field in supplied key"}`

I think the variable has the right information (at least it does when I debug it).

My end goal is a playbook that will add ssh keys of a list of hosts to a list of hosts for Jenkins auth.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `I think the variable has the right information (at least it does when I debug it).` <= I don't see any debugging output in your question. No one can guess the value you get and if it is correct or not. Before updating your question, you might want to check in depth that [the given key value meets the awaited format](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/known_hosts_module.html#parameter-key)

Comment: You can call `ssh-keyscan -t ed25519 myhost.mydomain.com` to specify the wanted keytype.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that the output of `ssh-keyscan myhost.mydomain.com 2>/dev/null` usually contains more than one key so you need to process it.
Someone with the same error message raised an [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/54661), but again the problem was with the ssh-key format. I better understood checking the [code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/known_hosts.py) used by `known_hosts` task.

Here the code I use:

```
- name: Populate known_hosts
  hosts: spectrum_scale
  tags: set_known_hosts
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Scan for SSH keys
    ansible.builtin.shell:
      cmd: "ssh-keyscan {{ hostvars[spectrum_scale].ansible_fqdn }} 
              {{ hostvars[spectrum_scale].ansible_hostname }} 
              {{ hostvars[spectrum_scale].ansible_default_ipv4.address }} 
              2>/dev/null"
    loop: "{{ groups['spectrum_scale'] }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: spectrum_scale
    register: ssh_scan

  - name: Set stdout_lines array for ssh_scan
    set_fact:
      ssout: []
  
  - name: Fill ssout
    set_fact:
      ssout: "{{ ssout + ss_r.stdout_lines }}"
    loop: "{{ ssh_scan.results }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var:
        ss_r
    when: ss_r.stdout_lines is defined

  - name: Add client ssh keys to known_hosts
    ansible.builtin.known_hosts:
      name: "{{ hk.split()[0] }}"
      key: "{{ hk }}"
      state: present
    loop: "{{ ssout }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: hk
```

Answer (score 0):

This small playbook distributes the host keys to each other to the `known_hosts` for a specific user (`SOME_USER`) on the specified target hosts/groups (`TARGETS`). The wanted keytype can be specified via the `keytype` variable.

This uses the `ansible_facts` which are gathered and the start of the playbook run.

To come back the the question, this does not directly answers it. But I think it can be enhanced. You could e.g. change the loop variable, add `myhost.mydomain.com` to the TARGETS, and more...

```
- hosts: TARGETS
  vars:
    keytype: ed25519
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.known_hosts:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        key: "{{ item }} {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_facts']['ssh_host_key_' + keytype + '_public_keytype'] }} {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_facts']['ssh_host_key_' + keytype + '_public'] }}"
        state: present
      when: "item != inventory_hostname"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
      become: yes
      become_user: SOME_USER
```